# Add-in installed, but its elements not appearing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, java, add-in, eclipse

I'm creating an Add-in for ArcMap 10.1.

When I export file [*testproject.esriaddin*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmgativ9sh02ymp/testproject.esriaddin) and install (whether double-click or from *Customize Mode > Add From File* dialog), message of success appears. But then, I can't find any of my elements in *Customize Mode* dialog (no *Java Tools* or *Java Commands* category, no toolbar in toolbars...).

I found [this topic](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/58305-Problems-with-java-add-ins), which seemed to be about the same problem. There, the solution was to select JRE: Java SE 1.6 instead of 1.7. I set this in my project, but the Add-in is still not working.

What could be wrong?

Here is my java class for the button:

```
package cz.upol.geoinformatics.veselka;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.esri.arcgis.addins.desktop.Button;
//import com.esri.arcgis.arcmapui.IMxDocument;
import com.esri.arcgis.framework.IApplication;
import com.esri.arcgis.interop.AutomationException;

public class Button1 extends Button {
    private IApplication app;
    //private IMxDocument projectDocument;

    /**
     * Called when the button is clicked.
     * 
     * @exception java.io.IOException if there are interop problems.
     * @exception com.esri.arcgis.interop.AutomationException if the component throws an ArcObjects exception.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick() throws IOException, AutomationException {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IApplication app){
        this.app = app;
        //this.projectDocument = (IMxDocument)app.getDocument();
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks after deploy to ArcMap:
[image: Add-in Manager in ArcMap]

I use ArcGIS + SDK 10.1 on Windows 7 32bit and Eclipse 4.3
Did I forgot to mention some details?

---

Edit: Here is my another screenshot: (You can see, that category *Java Commnads* is not listed in Categories)
[image: Screenshot Eclipse + ArcGIS Customize window]

Comment: I'm not a java developer but looking at your code it looks like you have created a button. From your screenshoot it looks like you have installed the addIn called "Test Add-In". You need to go to Customize > Customize mode > Commands tab and find the category you created the button in. That is documented in the esriconfig file.

Comment: I did. As I've written in the second paragraph. You can see on [my another screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xme441rs1mfdcuj/Screenshot%202014-05-06%2017.21.03.png), that category "Java Commands" is not listed.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud here, In VB .net one needs to set the  button image (in your case fuzzy-icon.jpg) to build action AddInContent, is that the same as in java? Also I tend to use bmp or png I did not know jpg was supported? In VB .net its framework 3.5 and I tend to set target cpu to x86 if these are relevant to java?

Comment: I don't think that it would be caused by image type. Image is optional. I changed it to PNG, but the result is same. What do You mean with setting target cpu to x86? I use x86 system.

Comment: ArcGIS is 32bit but you may be developing on a Windows 7 64bit machine and this can sometimes upset things, general advice on various forums is to set the build to compile to x86 rather than accept the default AnyCPU. I have to admit I'm talking from a VB perspective here so no idea if this is even relevant for java?

Comment: It could be relevant. They mention it in the topic on  arcgis.com I linked in above. But it is not my case, I use Win 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling ArcGIS, Java and also .NET Framework. So, I didn't figure out which part was causing it.

My steps:

1. Uninstalled ArcGIS 10.1, Java 1.7 (JRE and JDK) and .NET framework
   (probably 4.5.1) from my computer.
2. Used [The .NET cleanup tool](http://djlab.com/2010/10/how-to-completely-uninstall-net-framework/).
3. (Installed trial version of ArcGIS 10.2.1, but couldn't get ArcObjects SDK, then uninstalled.)
4. Installed ArcGIS.
5. Installed Java 1.6

   *At this time, everything was finaly working correctly!*
6. Installed .NET 4.5.1 through the Windows Update

Everything is still working.

Comment: having the same issue, unfortunately this answer doesn't help.